# How to insert old data to AggregatingMergeTree for AggregateFunction(count) column type in Clickhouse?

Tags: aggregate, clickhouse

I have old table:

```
CREATE TABLE old_stats
(
    id String,
    results_count UInt64
)
ENGINE = AggregatingMergeTree
PRIMARY KEY (id);
```

New aggregating table:

```
CREATE TABLE new_stats
(
    id String,
    results_count AggregateFunction(count)
)
ENGINE = AggregatingMergeTree
PRIMARY KEY (id);
```

How directly insert into `new_stats` from `old_stats`

```
INSERT INTO new_stats
SELECT
id,
result_count
FROM old_stats;
```

Not working solutions:

`countState(result_count) as result_count` makes exception `Conversion from AggregateFunction(count, UInt8) to AggregateFunction(count) is not supported`

`arrayReduce('countState', range(1, results_count))` makes exception `Conversion from AggregateFunction(count, UInt8) to AggregateFunction(count) is not supported`

Comment: Could you share a bit more about your use case? Considering the DDLs you provided, it seems that you could change the type of `result_count` in the `new_stats` table to `SimpleAggregateFunction(sum, UInt64)`.

Comment: `arrayReduce('CountState', range(results_count))`

Comment: `arrayReduce` not working, see my comment in with exception, `SimpleAggregateFunction` change column type is not a solution for me, I need to use same `AggregateFunction(count)` type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized the answer as I was working on a different project. Your column in the MV is of type `AggregateFunction(count)`, so you need to use the `countState` function to insert values into it.

Try the following query (it worked in a simple test I just ran):

```
INSERT INTO new_stats SELECT
    id,
    countState(results_count) AS results_count
FROM old_stats
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: Yes it will work just argument to pass need define column type as AggregateFunction(count, UInt64) or other column type which you will pass ;)

Answer (score 1):

If count is just a running total of integers, use `SimpleAggregateFunction`:

```
CREATE TABLE new_stats
(
    `id` String,
    `results_count` SimpleAggregateFunction(sum, UInt64)
)
ENGINE = AggregatingMergeTree
PRIMARY KEY id
```

Notice the result from the following inserts:

```
insert into old_stats values (1, 200);
insert into new_stats values (1,10);

SELECT * FROM new_stats FINAL

Query id: 718c2240-97ca-431c-b8cf-9690961100ad

┌─id─┬─results_count─┐
│ 1  │           210 │
└────┴───────────────┘
```

And...your query above will work fine (where you insert the old table into the new one)

Comment: SimpleAggregateFunction change column type is not a solution for me, I need to use same AggregateFunction(count) type

Comment: I don't understand what you are counting. What's your desired result?

Comment: new_stats table have, materilized view which consuming data from Kafka table engine, and doing countState() on every new record consumed by id, so I dont think that  SimpleAggregateFunction is sutes for me. But now when new stats table is consuming results, I need to import old stats from mysql, I have Mysql engine table imported and now I want to import them.

Comment: For each row in `old_stats`, can you run an INSERT into `new_stats`, without passing in a value for `results_count`? Just insert a new row into `new_stats` with  only the `id` column. Does `results_count` increment if you do that?

Comment: of course, but just by 1, I need to increment by `old_stats.results_count` value

Comment: How often do you need to perform this task? Is it only once? I realize it's a hack, but just write a for loop or something for each `id` and INSERT a row `results_count` number of times into `new_stats`.